# How specific does the weapon choice have to be when picking the Weapon Focus feat?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I'm wondering how specific the choice of the weapon has to be when a PC picks the [Weapon Focus](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/weapon-focus-combat---final) feat.

I assume the same is true for [Weapon Specialization](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/weapon-specialization-combat---final).

For example;

Could a PC take Weapon Focus: Bows or would it have to be Weapon Focus: Longbow

Would either one of those apply to Composite Bows as well?

My confusion comes from the fact that the Weapon Focus feat states the following;

> Choose one type of weapon. You can also choose unarmed strike or grapple (or *ray*, if you are a spellcaster) as your weapon for the purposes of this feat.

Emphasis mine.  It's unclear to me if as a spellcaster you have to pick 1 ray or rays in general so then I started wondering how specific you had to be with these feats.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For bows, you need to say the type of bow. For example longbow or short bow.

Composite bows use the same feats as the non-composite variant of the weapon.

[from the composite longbow description:](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons/weapon-descriptions/longbow-composite)

> For purposes of Weapon Proficiency and similar feats, a composite
>   longbow is treated as if it were a longbow.

For rays, weapon focus(ray) & weapon specialization(ray) is enough.

[from the faq](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9nef) (emphasis mine):

> Weapon Specialization: **Can you take Weapon Specialization (ray)** or
>   Improved Critical (ray) as feats? How about Weapon Specialization
>   (bomb) or Improved Critical (bomb)?
>
> **All four of those are valid choices**.
>
> Note that Weapon Specialization (ray) only adds to hit point damage caused by a ray attack that would normally deal hit point
>   damage; it doesn't increase ability score damage or drain (such as the
>   Dexterity drain from polar ray), penalties to ability scores (such as
>   from ray of enfeeblement) or drain, negative levels (such as from
>   enervation), or other damage or penalties from rays.